# Jetty starts with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource must not be null

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm using `WebAppContext` as the handler in embedded jetty:

```java
Server server = setupServerOfTwoConnectors();
server.setHandler(webAppContext());

server.start();
```

And the `webAppContext()` is:

```java
private static WebAppContext webAppContext() {
    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setContextPath("/foo");
    context.setWar("bar.war");

    return context;
}
```

Do I miss anything here? 
The jetty version is `9.2.10.v20150310`

This is the exception when starting up:

```
2015-06-05 10:57:45,015 [main] ERROR - [ContextLoader:331] Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.<init>(EncodedResource.java:66)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at my.code.JettySanityTest.setupJetty(JettySanityTest.java:56)
```

Comment: After some debugging, I found the root reason is a missing `-D` config in VM arguments

Answer (score 0):

> Without knowing what your war file needs from Jetty's configuration I'm just taking a stab in the dark with this answer.  (Adjust accordingly)

You'll want to declare some configuration behaviors for that webapp.

Eg:

```java
    context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] 
    { 
        new AnnotationConfiguration(),
        new WebInfConfiguration(), 
        new WebXmlConfiguration(),
        new MetaInfConfiguration(), 
        new FragmentConfiguration(), 
        new EnvConfiguration(),
        new PlusConfiguration(), 
        new JettyWebXmlConfiguration() 
    });
```

Note that order of these is important, and any of them could be considered optional.

- `AnnotationConfiguration` - configure webapp from annotations present in the bytecode
- `WebInfConfiguration` *(enabled by default)* - configure webapp from information in `WEB-INF` directories (of main webapp and libs)
- `WebXmlConfiguration` *(enabled by default)* - configure webapp metadata from information present in `WEB-INF/web.xml` (only from main webapp)
- `MetaInfConfiguration` *(enabled by default)* - configure webapp from information in `META-INF` directories (of main webapp and libs)
- `FragmentConfiguration` *(enabled by default)* - configure webapp metadata from information present in lib fragments
- `EnvConfiguration` - setup an JNDI env for webapp
- `PlusConfiguration` - establish / bind JNDI variables based on information collected in metadata from above configurations
- `JettyWebXmlConfiguration` *(enabled by default)* - configure webapp from main webapp's `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` (using Jetty's IoC XML language)

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer the question. the root reason of my issue is found (see comment in the question)